# R, ggplot2, jtools: johnson neyman plot error

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, interaction

I am desperately trying to plot a Johnson-Neyman Plot for the following interaction:

```
nxsc_20 <-lm(meandec20 ~ centered_nep*centered_selfcontrol + factor(study), data = allstudies_wide)
```

I get the following output:

```
Coefficients:
                                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                        0.28264    0.02260  12.508  < 2e-16 ***
centered_nep                       0.08998    0.01192   7.551 7.41e-14 ***
centered_selfcontrol               0.01894    0.01021   1.856  0.06364 .  
factor(study)2                     0.03462    0.02531   1.368  0.17146    
factor(study)3                     0.35767    0.02635  13.573  < 2e-16 ***
factor(study)4                     0.33224    0.03709   8.956  < 2e-16 ***
centered_nep:centered_selfcontrol  0.03706    0.01300   2.850  0.00443 **
```

Now I try to make a JN-Plot

```
johnson_neyman(nxsc_20, meandec20, centered_selfcontrol, alpha = 0.05, plot = TRUE)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Fehler in vmat[pred, pred] : Indizierung außerhalb der Grenzen (Error in vmat[pred, pred] : indexing out of range)
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pred =` option is not for the response variable but for the predictor you want to plot on the y-axis. This will work:

```
library(interactions)

allstudies_wide = data.frame(meandec20=rnorm(500),centered_nep = runif(500),
centered_selfcontrol = runif(500), study = sample(1:4,500,replace=TRUE))

nxsc_20 <-lm(meandec20 ~ centered_nep*centered_selfcontrol + factor(study), 
data = allstudies_wide)

johnson_neyman(model = nxsc_20, pred = centered_nep,modx = centered_selfcontrol)
```

[image]